# C++ Wordsearch Puzzle Grid 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, grid, 2d, wordsearch

I'm having an issue trying to read in a textfile (below) that contains letters for a wordsearch. I want to read the textfile in as an array then be able to match the words from my *dictionary.txt* to the *wordsearch_grid.txt*. Any ideas?

```
wordsearch_grid:
9
E M M A R G O R P 
C L U A U N L L D 
O T A O F I L O I 
M E U N J G E O K 
P W H K G G H P Q 
I C O M P U T E R 
L L V R Z B A O X 
E H O M L E Q G U 
T N I R P D C O E

dictionary:
COMPILE
COMPUTER
DEBUGGING
HELLO
KITCHEN
GRAPHICS
LOOP
SPAN
PROGRAMME
WORLD
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
#include "WordSearch.h"
#include "fstream"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "vector"


using namespace std;

vector<string> list;
vector<string> grid;
string line;
string n;

WordSearch::WordSearch(const char * const filename) 
{


}

WordSearch::~WordSearch() 
{

}

void WordSearch::ReadSimplePuzzle() {

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("wordsearch_grid.txt");

    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error Wordsearch Grid File" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {

        while (getline (inFile, n))
        {
            cout << n << endl;          
        }
        //grid[4][3];
        inFile.close();
        //cout << grid << endl;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }

}

void WordSearch::ReadSimpleDictionary() 
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("dictionary.txt");


    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Error Dictionary File" << endl;
        exit(1);

    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            list.push_back(line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }


}

void WordSearch::SolvePuzzleSimple() 

{


}
```

So far it can read in the files and display them but I want to be able to manipulate the grid so that it I can match the first and last letter of say "COMPILE" to match up with 2 letters in the grid and output to output.txt "COMPILE was found at [1][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the inline logic which you can encapsulate in your class how you choose :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

ifstream inFile("wordsearch_grid.txt");
ifstream dict("dictionary.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");

int main(){
    string word;
    char c;
    char grid[9][9] = {};
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    vector<string> wordsFound;
    clock_t start;
    double duration;
    vector<string> words;
    vector<vector<int> > locations;
    //store words from dictionary into vector
    while (getline(dict, word))
    { 
        words.push_back(word);     
    }
    start = clock();
    //store grid in a c-array
    while (inFile.get(c))
    {
        if (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
        {
            grid[row][column] = c;
            if (column == 8)
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }else
            {
                column++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    duration = (clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time it took to populate grid (seconds) : " << duration << endl;
    start = clock();
    //for each character in grid
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            //cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
            //for each word
            for (int k = 0; k < words.size(); k++)
            {
                //check if grid letter equals the first letter of word
                if (grid[i][j] == words[k][0])
                {
                    //check horizontal vertical and diagonal
                    for (int l = 1; l <= words[k].size(); l++)
                    {
                        if (
                            //break if no word was found
                            grid[i-l][j] != words[k][l] && 
                            grid[i+l][j] != words[k][l] && 
                            grid[i][j+l] != words[k][l] && 
                            grid[i][j-l] != words[k][l] &&
                            grid[i+l][j+l] != words[k][l] &&
                            grid[i-l][j-l] != words[k][l] && 
                            grid[i+l][j-l] != words[k][l] &&
                            grid[i-l][j+l] != words[k][l] )
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (l == words[k].size()-1)
                        {
                            //else write word found to file
                            //out << words[k] << " was found at [" <<
                            //j+1 << "][" << i+1 << "]" << endl;
                            //add word location to locations
                            vector<int> location;
                            location.push_back(j+1);
                            location.push_back(i+1);
                            locations.push_back(location);
                            //add word to wordsFound
                            wordsFound.push_back(words[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //cout << endl;
    }
    duration = (clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time it took to finish wordsearch puzzle (seconds) : " << duration << endl;

    out << "number of words found: " << wordsFound.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsFound.size(); i++){
        out << wordsFound[i] << " was found at [" << locations[i][0] << "][" << locations[i][1] << "]" << endl;
    }
    out << "number of words not found: " << words.size() - wordsFound.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordsFound.size(); j++) {
            //loop to check if word in dictionary wasn't found and append to output.txt
            if (words[i] == wordsFound[j]){
                break;
            }
            else if (j == wordsFound.size()-1){
                out << words[i] << " was not found!" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apologies I wanted to ask one last thing but didn't know if an answered question would allow that. How do I go about printing the wordsearch_grid using cout, I could before but I can't with your line of code. Thank you once again it's perfect.

Comment: No worries, oh right, i've edited the question so it prints each character in each row and prints a new line, at the end of every row.

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed 10/10.

Comment: Jack I was wondering if you knew of anyway I could tell how many words are found, time it took to solve the puzzle and time it took to populate the grid?

Comment: You could increment an int variable, wordsFound, each time you find a word and print it once the program completes. As for the benchmarking, since you didn't include c++11 tags, you're probably best to use a clock from the ctime library. I've edited the answer to show how it would be used.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm guessing to output the number of words not found is the same deal?

Comment: One way is to change `wordsFound` to a vector and keep track of words found. Then you can loop through all words in the dictionary, `words`, and `wordsFound` and output the words in the dictionary that weren't in `wordsFound` (see the new edit).

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to print out(to the out file) Number of Words founds BEFORE Words Matched as putting the code for number of words found within the nested for loop or before doesn't work, it returns 1 found then increments and prints with every new Word Matched. I've tried a few things but the solution I ended up with results in all words being found at the same point [70][1].

Comment: You could use a 2D vector and store the location when you find a word. Then you can loop through outputting the word and its corresponding location after you output how many words were found(see edit).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code. I hope it's clear how you can load and work with the grid. Now you just have to load your dictionary and write the result into the file.

```
std::vector<char> grid;
unsigned int grid_size = 0;

void load_grid(const std::string &path) {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(path);

    inFile >> grid_size;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < grid_size*grid_size; i++) {
        char letter;
        inFile >> letter;
        grid.push_back(letter);
    }
}

bool search_word(int x, int y, const std::string &word) {
    // horizontal
    if (x + word.length() <= grid_size) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while (i < word.length() && grid[y*grid_size + x + i] == word[i]) i++;
        if (i == word.length()) return true;
    }
    // vertical
    if (y + word.length() <= grid_size) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while (i < word.length() && grid[(y+i)*grid_size + x] == word[i]) i++;
        if (i == word.length()) return true;
    }
    // diagonal
    if (x + word.length() <= grid_size && y + word.length() <= grid_size) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while (i < word.length() && grid[(y+i)*grid_size + x + i] == word[i]) i++;
        if (i == word.length()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {

    load_grid("wordsearch_grid.txt");

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < grid_size; x++) {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < grid_size; y++) {
            if (search_word(x, y, "WORLD")) {
                std::cout << "WORLD starts at: " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'm having an issue with &word but apart from that I see what it does.